# NGINX: Rewrite url to change to hash/anchor

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm having a hard time trying to tell NGINX to rewrite certain URL's, which contain &option=xxxx in the url.

An URL is constructed of the domain part (http://www.test.com/), a database reference part (?database=demo) and consecutive variables (&xxxx=xxxx). I would like the first instance of the & to always be #

The original URL looks like this:

http://www.test.com/?database=demo&option=sign&type=new

I would like NGINX to rewrite the URL to:

..website../?database=demo#option=sign&type=new

Notice the change from &option to #option.

To complicate things, the next URL should be left unchanged, because it is not the first instance of an & and the # has already been set:

..website../?database=demo#model=process&activion=none&option=sign&type=new

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Maybe it would be easier to tell NGINX to replace the first & in the URL to and # if it is not already a #, as that is the effect I'm after. Even here I'm lost on how to achieve this.

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: You need to understand that nginx can redirect to URI with hash, but nginx can't see hash part in incoming request (because hash - it's for browser). So if you enter /?database=demo#model=process&activion=none&option=sign&type=new - nginx will see only /?database=demo.

Comment: I understand that the processing is done on totally different locations. # is client side, while & does get delivered to the server. The problem i was solving had a totally different solution, after some trying. I send the variables using both & and # so that they get processed on both sides, in Javascript and PHP. so http://www.test.com/?database=demo&option=sign&type=new#&option=sign&type=new, which works for me.

Comment: Strange solution :) JavaScript can process /?database=demo&option=sign&type=new without any hash too.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if query string has only database=demo or not. If not - redirect with hash. As i told, if in browser you will type /?database=demo#model=process - nginx will get only /?database=demo

```
location / {
   if ($args ~ "^database=demo&(.+)$") {
       set $optherargs $1;
       return 301 /?database=demo#$otherargs;
   }
}
```

But this solution is args order sensitive, database=demo need to be first param